# execute immediate in creating a table PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I would just like to ask why this code does not create the table?

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table temp1  as (select * from table)';
   COMMIT;
END;
```

when I try this, it creates the table but no record/data.

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table temp1';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table temp1  as (select * from table)';
   COMMIT;
END;
```

the `table` is a global temp table that is why there are no data when I select, but when I run the report, the output has data.

I am trying to fix a duplicate data error that is why I need to create the temp table.

Comment: First, you don't need to commit DDL operations (create, alter, drop , truncate), they auto-commit. Second , are you sure it didn't create the table? How have you looked? try to place the schema on which you want the table to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Data in a global temp table (GTT) is only accessible to the session that inserted it; other sessions will only see their own data. It's a common misunderstanding that the data in a global temporary table is not "global" - only the table definition is "global", the data in that table is local to the session that inserted it, and automatically cleared when the session ends (or commits, depending on what type of GTT it is).

If your report queries a GTT and finds data, there must have been a process which populated the global temp table first.

When you ran your "create table" statement (which, by the way, does not need to be explicitly committed), it queried the GTT and found no records because the session in which you created the table did not first populate the GTT with the data needed.